# Google Cloud Build - Github Trigger - Filter Files Don't Work

Tags: google-cloud-build

When Github Trigger is set to listen a tag the files filter is ignored and the trigger is set on every push

I have tried different settings on multiple triggers and nothing works

I've tried using a path like this packages/backend-node/src/* and didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

I noticed something similar but found the following in the docs:

> If you push a change to a newly created branch, then Cloud Build
> treats all the files in the repository as changed files.

So pushing a new branch to your repo will always trigger your build and ignore the file filters.

Source: https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/automating-builds/create-manage-triggers#build_trigger (the link no longer includes the quote from above)

Open bug report in google's issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/217776771